# How to redirect using .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to do something like this...

Redirect `www.mysite.com/directory/*` to my `subdommain.mysite.com/directory/*`

Please help me

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^directory/(.*)$ http://subdommain.mysite.com/directory/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I want like it

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your .htaccess file if you want to redirect all requests from `www.mysite.com` to `subdomain.mysite.com`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Try adding this to your .htaccess file if you want to redirect only requests for `/anydirectory/` from `www.mysite.com/anydirectory/` to `subdomain.mysite.com/anyotherdirectory/`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^anydirectory/(.*)$ http://subdommain.mysite.com/anyotherdirectory/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: include all file in folder directory

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean? My answer should redirect all requests to `www.mysite.com/anything/can/go/here` to `subdomain.mysite.com/anything/can/go/here`, is that not what you want?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you meant by the question. What you have posted in your question is working for me?